# Placing a <select> field using Django templates with custom bootstrap styles

Tags: html, django, django-templates, bootstrap-4, mdbootstrap

I am having an issues connecting my `html` `css` `javascript` front-end with `django`. I have `html` templates that look and work exactly as I want them too. I can display data without issue with I make a call to a `django` field that is part of my current view using:

```
<a>{{ thing.attribute }}</a>
```

That works great.

My issue is when trying to connect a form to the `django` view I created for updating and creating records using a `POST` action. For example, when using an `mdbootstrap` themed template, I have implemented an `html` `<select>` object like this:

```
<select type="select" class="mdb-select" id="fieldOne">
    <option value="0">Something</option>
    <option value="1">Something</option>
    <option value="2">Something</option>
</select>
```

This works and looks exactly like I want it too as it is correctly utilizing the proper `css` and `javascript`.

When I want to place a `django` form object in place of the same field, I have to call it like this:

```
<div class="mdb-select">{{ thing.attribute }}</div>
```

I have to call it as a `<div>` in `django`, and it's breaking my `css` and `javascript`, thus not displaying correctly and not usable. I can see the data being returned when I look at the rendered `html` in dev tools, so I know my `django` views and forms are working.

Is there any way to call a `django` object while still utilizing the `<select>` tags in my `html` template?

Comment: You are using django forms right?

Comment: Yes, I am using django forms.

Comment: Are these model forms or regular forms?

Comment: They are defined in forms.py, view.py, and the model is defined in models.py. The html is a template. I am still very new to django, so my understanding of the terminaology is a bit unreliable. I followed this example on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/Forms

Comment: I am have the same problem with most of my html fields as MDBootstrap requires the specific <tag> to function properly (e.x. <select>, <input>, etc.).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) If you're using model forms, do one one this:
    Use [django widget_tweaks](https://pypi.org/project/django-widget-tweaks/) and then in your template do this:

`{% load widget_tweaks %}`

```
<label>{{my_form.field.label}}</label>
{% render_field my_form.field class="mdb-select" name="field" %}
```

OR

```
class NewSomethingForm(ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Account
    fields = ['name', 'last_name', 'description']

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.fields['description'].widget = forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'md-textarea', 'style': 'height: 75px'})`enter code here`
```

2) If you're not using model forms, then in your template, try this:

```
<select type="select" class="mdb-select" id="fieldOne" name=field>
    <option value="my_form.field_name.field.choices.0">my_form.field_name.field.choices.1</option>
    <!–– follow same sequence -- >
</select>
```

Don't forget to give the dropdown element a name that matches the field on the form.

Comment: widget_tweaks did the job perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can render a select field using Django ModelChoiceField. When you use this form in template using **{{yourForm.select_field_name}}** it will be rendered as  with

id:id_select_field_name

name:select_field_name

The css classes you need to associate are included in attrs

```
from django import forms
class yourForm(forms.Form):
    select_field_name=forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=recieptDetail.objects.all(), widget = forms.Select(attrs = {'class':"class-name",'onchange' : "jsFunction();"}))
```